# Vue 2 Laravel 5.3 POST method submit with token mismatch

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, csrf

Not sure how to set up `csrf_token` properly. here is my codes related

Item-card.vue

```
<template>
.....
.....
    <input v-if="selected == 'name' + product.id" v-model="name" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" @blur.prevent="updateName">
    <form id="update-product-name" :action="'http://localhost:8000/updateProductName/'+product.id" method="POST" style="display: none;">
.....
.....
</template>
<script>
.....
.....
   methods:{
      updateName(){
        document.getElementById('update-product-name').submit();
      }
   }
.....
.....
</script>
```

app.blade.php

```
<head>
.....

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta id="token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
.....
</head>
```

app.js

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $("#token").attr("value");
```

Reloaded page and it shows:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

I did some research and found that I dont have to add `csrf_token` in every single form I submit and just need to put it in the head meta tag. However it does not seem to work. How should it be set up?

EDIT#1

I did a bit of research and changed `attr("value")` into `attr("content")` but the same issue happens to me.

Comment: @Saurabh help please

Comment: You're not using `Vue.http` to submit the form so it's not going to include the header.

Comment: thanks for your response @RossWilson! so what would you suggest me to do instead for submitting the form?

Comment: Well looking at your code I'm assuming you have vue resource pulled in so I'd suggest using that. https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md

Comment: `oh ya! i have been using this for get method but what i have never thought of this god sake... i have been stucked like this for 2 days already. Let me give it a try first

Comment: @RossWilson Thanks for your response. I think this is as simple as that. Please feel free to answer the question directly so that I can make yours the correct answer. This is of enormous help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments the reason you were getting a `TokenMismatchException` was because the csrf header was not being sent.

> Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $("#token").attr("content");

The above will allow you to include the csrf header when using Vue-Resource.

You will need to change the behaviour of your form so that it gets submitted with vue/vue-resource instead of the default browser submission.

One way to do this would be:

```
updateName() {

    let data = {
        //Add the data you want to be sent in the request here e.g.
        //name: this.name
    }

    this.$http.post('/updateProductName/' + this.product.id, data)
        .then(r => {
            //Do something on success
        })
        .catch(r => console.log(r))
}
```

Hope this helps!